# C# - HiddenField values changes after Button Click

Tags: c#, jquery

I have a form which captures a few information and, using JQuery, checks against a database if the company already exists and sets a hiddenfield value of YES or NO.

Textbox for input as follows

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_CompanyName" runat="server" CssClass="Quote-Contact-Textbox-style" placeholder="COMPANY NAME" required="required"></asp:TextBox>
```

Jquery code to check if this company exists

```
$('#<%=txt_CompanyName.ClientID%>').blur(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Fetch/VerifyIfCompanyExists.aspx',
                data: {
                    CompanyName: $('#<%=txt_CompanyName.ClientID%>').val(),
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    var data = result.split('|');
                    if (data[0] == "RED") {
                        alert('This company already exists in the CRM');
                        $('#<%=hdn_CustAlreadyExists.ClientID%>').val("YES");
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#<%=hdn_CustAlreadyExists.ClientID%>').val("NO");
                    }
                    if (data[1] != "0") {
                        $('#<%=hdn_ExistingCompanyID.ClientID%>').val(data[1]);
                        $('#<%=hdn_QueryDB.ClientID%>').val("LiveDB");
                    }
                    if (data[2] == "RED") {
                        alert('You have already quoted this customer');
                    }
                    if (data[3] != "0") {
                        $('#<%=hdn_ExistingCompanyID.ClientID%>').val(data[3]);
                        $('#<%=hdn_QueryDB.ClientID%>').val('QuoteDB');
                    }
                }

            });
```

So if the company exists, it sets the hdn_CustAlreadyExists value to 'YES'. I have checked (using alerts) that the field value is indeed set to 'YES' and it is.

This is the button to submit the form

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_CreateQuote" runat="server" Text="CREATE QUOTE" OnClick="btn_CreateQuote_Click" CssClass="Quote_Create_Button" />
```

When I check the code behind, it return the value 'NO' instead of 'YES'.

```
ExistingCustomer = hdn_CustAlreadyExists.Value;
```

Not sure why this is happening. Can someone please let me know how to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Just curious...$('#<%=hdn_ExistingCompanyID.ClientID%>')   Is this valid?
Or do you need to  $('#'+<%=hdn_ExistingCompanyID.ClientID%>) ?

Comment: Are you setting `hdn_CustAlreadyExists.Value` anywhere in the code-behind?

Comment: Michael - I am not setting any values for hdn_CustAlreadyExists in the code-behind

Comment: Add the markup for the HiddenField. Also, in which method are you checking `hdn_CustAlreadyExists.Value`?

Comment: I am checking the value on the button click method - protected void btn_CreateQuote_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: and the markup for the hiddenfield is <asp:HiddenField ID="hdn_CustAlreadyExists" runat="server" />

Comment: Funny enough, the other fields are holding their value.

Comment: In the Network tab of your browser's Developer Tools, examine the request sent to the server when clicking the button. If the value of the hidden field is NO, then there's a bug in the JavaScript -- something is setting the field to NO before the form is submitted. If the value of the hidden field in the request is YES but the value is NO in the Click method, then something really weird is going on...

Comment: That's a good point, I just checked and the form is being submitted as 'NO' - ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hdn_CustAlreadyExists:NO

Comment: Just rewrote the jquery exactly the same and it now works! I do not understand what was the problem but resolved! Thanks Michael